# "Посёлок" или "пасёлок"?

Tags: орфография

Проверочное слово к слову *посёлок*

Answer (score 1):

однозначно, "по" приставка, "па" приставки не бывает, а "сел" корень, от слова село

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы лучше понять и запомнить правописание слова **посёлок** посмотрите на словообразовательную цепочку:

> *что делать?* **сел/и/ть** → *что сделать?* **по/сел/и/ть** -> *что?* **по/сёл/ок**

Морфема **по-** является в данном случае приставкой. В русском языке есть только приставка *по-*, приставки **па-* нет.

Comment: Как же нет? А в словах "пасынок" и "паводок" чем является "па-"?

Comment: @Пересвет Вы правы, перестарался с приставкой *па-*. Приставка в современном языке есть, хотя и непродуктивна.

Answer (score 0):

по- в данном случае приставка

Answer (score 0):

В селении можно поселиться, "по-" - это приставка.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **посёлок** (приставка **по-**; корень -сёл-; суффикс -ок).

Нельзя говорить, что приставки **па-** не существует.
В современном русском литературном языке есть слова с такой приставкой:
паводок, паводковый, паводочный, паволока, паголенки, пагубно, пагубность, пагубный, падуб, падчерица, паклен, пасека, пасечник, пасмурный, пасмурно, пасока, пасочный, патока, паузок, пасынок.
Некоторые слова приводятся с ограничительными пометами: паужин (устар., обл.), паузить (спец.), паузка (спец.), пащенок (прост., бран.), пагуба (устар., высок.), падуга (театр.)

Стоит отметить, что устаревшая (или архаичная, или малопродуктивная) приставка **па-** всегда находится под ударением.

P. S. Слова [па́сека](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [па́тока](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) исследователи языка рассматривают по-разному.